# Get main colors of pixels in an image

Tags: python, opencv, colors, color-detection

Im trying to get all the colors of my Image. Im doing it with

```
unique_rgbs = np.unique(resized_img.reshape(-1, resized_img.shape[2]), axis=0)
```

My expectation would be to get 6 Colors, but I get something about 2000 because the border between colors is not solid. I then changed the colors of my image, so that it would only have colors red[255,0,0] green[0,255,0] blue[255,0,0], and yellow[0,255,255], and tried to get rid of all other colors with the following code

```
img[img[...,0] > 128] = 255
img[img[...,0] <= 128] = 0
 
img[img[...,1] > 128] = 255
img[img[...,1] <= 128] = 0
 
img[img[...,2] > 128] = 255
img[img[...,2] <= 128] = 0
```

but it is not working. The resulting image is only black and white and the result of `np.unique` says that there are 26 colors in the image.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGmSz.jpg)

[zoomed in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x5p4.png)

Comment: If you have control over the original image, don't use jpeg. It's lossy and can cause artifacts like these. Try using png instead.

Comment: My input image is png

Comment: You seem to have shared a JPEG.

Comment: Is the image you have shared truly representative of your images? Are all the images you want to process composed purely of highly saturated, primary colours? Do you have other examples?

Comment: @Tereza Cool, I only mentioned it for future reference since the original image you posted was a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering seems to work in this case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = plt.imread("xGmSz.jpg").reshape(-1, 3)

# cluster pixels
N = 6
km = KMeans(n_clusters=N, init="k-means++")
km.fit(X)
# get cluster centers
colors = km.cluster_centers_.astype(int)
plt.imshow(cen.reshape(1, N, 3))
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the Answer, but the thing is, i want to use the code also on other Pictures without knowing the count of the colors and defining it manually